# After catching an error but except statement not resolving, is it good standard/makes sense to throw an exception?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a function that potentially throws an error, which is why I have code to catch the error. But if for some reason my code in the except statement does not resolve the error, is it **good standard** to throw an exception on purpose after the code has resolved? Obviously indicating that there is maybe some additional code that needs to be added.

Please see below for an example:

```
error_counter = 0
error_limit = 10
completed = False
while error_limit > error_counter and not completed:
    try:
        # Do something
        completed = True
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Trying again...')
        error_counter += 1
        # Code to resolve error (wait longer or other etc.)
if error_counter >= error_limit:
    raise Exception('error, code needs updating!')
```

I have updated the original question to be clearer and more correct. Please check edit log if you need to.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in ways that might invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Chris has a good point.  The correct<footnote>1</footnote> way to deal with an egregious mistake in your Question is to make it clear to the reader that you corrected the mistake; e.g.  don't replace the bad code with better code, but add the better code below, flagged as an **UPDATE**.   Better still, don't make the mistake in the first place!  <footnote>1 - correct per the consensus standards of SO ... based on 10+ years of doing it.</footnote>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted to implement that logic, I would write it like this:

```
error_counter = 0
error_limit = 10
completed = False
while not completed:
    try:
        # Do something
        completed = True
    except ValueError as e:
        error_counter += 1
        if error_counter >= error_limit:
            # bail out!
            raise Exception('error, code needs updating!')
        else:
            print('Trying again...')
            # Code to resolve error
```

This version of the code is more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  The logic for handling the retrying and ultimate failure handling is in one place.  It makes it easier to understand.

> But if for some reason my code in the except statement does not resolve the error, is it good standard to throw an exception on purpose after the code has resolved?

I'm not going to say what is "good standard" (because there is no standard!) or "good practice" (because that is a matter of opinion).  However:

- Catching an exception and immediately raising a different one is a *common* practice.  Lots of code does this.
- In general, raising an exception to indicate that some part of your code has failed ... is what exceptions are designed for.

---

<sup>In Java ... it is widely accepted that throwing `Exception` is a bad idea.  But the strongest reason against doing this is to do with checked vs unchecked exceptions.  Python doesn't make that distinction.</sup>

Comment: hey, thanks. this is helpful and I am always looking to learn. correct, I just randomly inserted the `ValueError`, because I just wanted to illustrate on a high level what I was thinking.... of course this is not the error that I am dealing with.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use a loop conditional on a boolean variable like `completed` version `while True:` and then a `break` where appropriate.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion too.  Either works, but when you write code you have to make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question leans heavily into opinion, but...

Your while loop is only broken and continues onto the following code if `error_limit` is less than or equal to `error_counter`, *or rather* if `error_counter` is greater than or equal to `error_limit`.

Thus the condition `error_counter >= error_limit` is always true. As such, this is not an exceptional circumstance, so an exception seems a little out of place.

Having said that, there is nothing wrong with catching an exception, handling it, then throwing a *different* exception for your code to handle at another level.